# Draw best fit line from ImageJ selection

Tags: image, line, imagej, best-fit

Trying to find a way to convert either:

1. a multi-point selection or
2. a segmented line into a best fit line.

Within the Edit>Selection tools I see plenty of options for fit circle, spline, and elipse, but am struggling to find a solution.

I found a plugin ([Fitline by Nucmed](http://www.med.harvard.edu/JPNM/ij/plugins/FitLineTP.html)) that uses results of multi-point selections to draw a best fit line, but haven't had luck superimposing the results back over the original image.

[image: ImageJ best fit line]

Comment: Can you please link to the *Fitline plugin* you're talking about? I wasn't able to find it on the [list of plugins](http://imagej.net/plugins/).

Comment: It is a third party plug-in available here:
http://www.med.harvard.edu/JPNM/ij/plugins/FitLineTP.html